# Combinatorics of fourth order feynman diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

I am trying to calculate how many different forth order feynman loop diagrams I can produce. I know that for 2nd order it is 6x3x2 thus 3! since you start with 3 lines coming out of each vertex so 6 lines in total, one of them connects with the incoming line, one from the other vertex has to connect with outgoing line and you have 2 ways to connect remaining 2 lines in each vertex thus 6x3x2.

[image]

But what happens when you have 4 vertices? I started with 12x9 since one line has to connect in incoming and one from remaining 3 vertices should connect with outgoing but I am not sure about the rest. I can say that for the remaining 10 lines I want 2 combinations of 10 and then subtract the ones which connect lines in a way that does not produce a loop diagram.

[image]

So how many different ways there are for this diagram?